# Сбрасывается пароль. pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql

Установил postgresql, поставил пароль на пользователя postgres. Все хорошо работало, потом начал добавлять других пользователей. Теперь все пользователи, включая самого postgres, могут авторизоваться без пароля. Я пытался установить пароль через passwd, alter user, через оболочку pgadmin. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так или хотя бы в какую сторону копать ?

Comment: Проверьте свой `pg_hba.conf`, не настроен ли он на `trust` вход.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Поменял метод trust на нужный мне. Оставляю ссылку, может кому полезно будет.

https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/auth-pg-hba-conf.html